# Magento 1.9 can't link a product to a specific store view

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, products, store-view, stores

I have magento 1.9.3.2 and i have multiple store views

[image]

i can't link a specific product to a specific store (for example jordan store) because it force me to select main website only which includes the 2 stores together

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento not giving option to set product store vice

you can implement alternative for it

Go to store view select particular store in which you want to disable product

set **status** to **disable**

You can also instead of setting the status disabled, just change the visibility then.